# Make script to add empty to head of bone

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to use `bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].edit_bones['Bone'].head), scale=(1, 1, 1))` to place an empty at the head of a bone. I have a lot of bones that need this, and I need this done on a few models with the same armature.

I get a context error when I try using this code. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

```
    Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 3, in <module>
  File "D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.2\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 115, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.empty_add.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

EDIT:

I've tried using this script to move the 3D cursor to the head and placing an empty there, but I am getting a context error again.

```
def add_empties(thebones):
    bpy.data.objects['Armature'].select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.data.objects['Armature'].data.edit_bones[thebones].select_head = True
    bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))



Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 13, in <module>
  File "\Text", line 7, in add_empties
  File "D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.2\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 115, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

I found the error, but it's still not moving the cursor. Really super confused on everything now. It would have been faster to do it by hand =/

bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### `bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()` will raise error in Editmode but not in Object mode

```
import bpy

def add_empties(obj_name, bone_name):
    # set active object
    obj = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

    # to editmode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    bone = obj.data.edit_bones[bone_name]
    bone.select_head = True

    loc = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location

    # change head to 3dcursor location
    bone.head = loc

    # add empty
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=loc, scale=(1, 1, 1))

add_empties("Armature", "Bone")
```

Comment: bone.head = loc actually causes the bone heads to change position to world origin.

I omitted the bpy.context.scene.cursor.location and replaced with loc = bone.head and it works perfectly